# ERROR: type modifier is not allowed for type "geometry" in PostGIS 2.1

Tags: postgresql, debian, postgis, postgresql-9.1

On Debian Wheezy I had postgresql 9.1 installed and installed the postGIS 1.5 from the standard apt repo. This didn't have the geometry type however so I added the postgresql apt repo and installed postgis 2.1:

```
sudo apt-get install postgis-2.1
```

the last output of which related to postgis was:

```
Setting up postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.2 (2.2.1+dfsg-2.pgdg70+1)
```

All appeared good but when I run the following sql the same error as in postGIS 1.5 results:

```
ALTER TABLE bolls ADD COLUMN location geometry(POINT,-1);
```

Edit:
After instruction from Nick Barnes in comment below I tried `ALTER EXTENSION postgis update to "2.1";` and got

```
ERROR:  extension "postgis" does not exist
```

If I try `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` it tells me PostGIS is already installed.

Comment: Did you run `ALTER EXTENSION ... UPDATE`? Installing the package makes the new version available, but it won't modify your databases.

Comment: updated question accordingly

Comment: Apparently 1.5->2.0+ upgrades are not possible via a simple extension update; a dump/restore of the database is required (see [here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/release_notes.html#idp112059824)). This isn't the error message I'd expect, though, so there may be other issues...

Comment: By the way, as long as you're doing a dump/restore of the database, you might want to consider upgrading from Postgres 9.1 (which will be EOL in September).

Answer (score 1):

To go from version 1.5 to 2.1, follow the [**hard upgrade** instructions in the manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade). These steps, in brief, are:

1. Dump the old database to a file
2. Spatially enable a new empty database (you've already done this with `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`)
3. Use a special utility `postgis_restore.pl` that came with your new version of PostGIS to translate the old format to  the new format.

Also `geometry(POINT,-1)` is invalid. If you don't have an SRID, it's just `geometry(POINT)`.